# Unable to modify MyOpportunities List View

Tags: list-view

I can't seem to modify the standard **My Opportunities** list view in our org. I was able to modify this view in my own developer org without any issues.

Some searching online showed that there are two permissions related to editing list views: **Manage Public List View** and **Create and Customize List Views**. I verified and both of these permissions are available to me on my profile (I'm using the standard admin profile).

The last modified user was an admin that is still active so I logged in as him and could not update the view. The creator was no longer active so I re-activated the user and try again, and still could not update the view.

The error I get is:

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation
>   error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first
>   validation error encountered was "This View Unique Name already exists
>   or has been previously used. Please choose a different name.".
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Does anyone know what I need to do to enable this functionality? I know it can be done I just don't know what's stopping me from doing it.

Comment: Have you tried just changing its name?

Comment: @sfdcfox It's the standard view that all our reps use. I know that I could just create a new custom view but I should be able to modify this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its a known issue from salesforce side. Please look into the below link for more info.

[This View Unique Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BigQAE)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround didn't work for me as I didn't wanted to change the existing list view name or create a new list view.

I was able to retrieve the list view and make changes to XML and save/deploy via VScode.

Comment: This is a good approach +1